# Compose Anonymous type from another type using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a simple class:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set;}

    public string FirstName { get; set;}

    public string LastName { get; set;}

    public string NameSummary { get; set;}

}
```

I have collection of Tests.

I want to create anonymous class from Test class that has only Id and NameSummary properties. How can I acoomplish this using linq?

```
Tests.OrderBy(s => s.FirstName).Select( new ( Id, NameSummary)) // not sure how to do this
```

Edit:
I managed to do this like this. I was having problems use the Select statement the right way.

```
Tests.OrderBy(s => s.FirstName).Select(  s => new  { Id = s.Id, NameSummary = s.NameSummary, })
```

Comment: What didn't you understand in the docs? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Tests.OrderBy(s => s.FirstName).Select(s=> new { s.Id, s.NameSummary});
```